# Bottom aligned text, line break upwards?

Tags: css

I am using absolute positioning to put text at the bottom of a div. Pay attention to the white text at the bottom of the image. Thats the text I am talking about.

[image]

---

The problem with this text is that when the line breaks, it pushes the majority of the text to the top line, and puts the extra text on the bottom line. I would instead prefer if the majority of text stayed on the bottom line and the extra text got pushed to the top... example in the image below:

[image]

---

Is something like this possible with CSS?

Comment: so like you are writing down up and not the classic up down

Comment: Sort of... I still want the beginning of the sentence to be at the top though.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML? This isn't possible with CSS if that text is all together.

Comment: I can edit the HTML... but hard coding in line breaks wouldn't resolve with responsive design.

Comment: You'll have to tell the browser where you want the line break, either with line breaks, or wrapping the groups of words in spans or something. CSS can't target text nodes..

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of a suggestions. The first one is to justify the text-align; i.e. see below

```
.some-selector{
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

The other suggestion, which I am in favor of as it is more stable, is to divide your text into a number of p elements; for instance as below. However, you will need to test it well when reducing the browser, or using your page on mobile devices.

```
<div>
    <p>Line1.</p>
    <p>Line2.</p>
    <p>Line3.</p>
</div>
```

I may have more suggestions if I can see some snippet, Fiddle, or CodePen of your code.