# With TextView alignment bottom, line breaks are at the top

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

*A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130545/bottom-aligned-text-line-break-upwards), though not for Android development and it hasn't been answered in a sufficient way.*

In my app I want to align text to the bottom right.
So far so good.
However, I want my line breaks to respect the given gravity, so that the longer text is at the bottom.

Example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
> elit. Cras sollicitudin

should look more like

> Lorem ipsum dolor 
> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sollicitudin

My `TextView` looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

I expected `android:gravity="bottom|end"` to give me the desired result but as far as I can tell it didn't change anything.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573619/5696047

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani Thanks, though I'm currently working on my own implementation of the `TextView` class, whcih I'll post as soon as it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible only with TextView attributes. You should write your own TextView to modify the behavior.